# Would it be possible to replace sqlite with MySQL in Firefox?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, firefox

Do you think that it could be done so Firefox doesn't use sqlite for its internal storage and make it use MySQL instead? Of course that would require setting up MySQL on the host, etc. but that's easy. Or some people could even make it use a separate MySQL machine in LAN if they actually run one.

The reason i'm asking is that sqlite seems to perform way slower than MySQL and it also tends to lag the Firefox when it is heavily used. It can be heavy on I/O, too. Also storing the data in MySQL would make it much easier for people to export or even just access/modify/browse them.

Comment: Of course it could be done, but I don't think your assumptions are even nearly correct

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem; your real issue is that your queries are slow, which is likely because of a poor schema or lack of indexes. Additionally, you need to tell us what sort of program you are writing: a plug in? JS application?